# Reading the contents of an HTML element from a Smart Contract Written in Solidity

Tags: html, web, blockchain, solidity

I am creating a smart contract, one in which I require the ability to read the contents of an HTML element (the price of something, an integer), and then confirm whether or not sufficient funds (in accordance with the integer stored within that element) have been transferred to my address. How do I read the contents of an element?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: @1m2n3 Welcome to SO.
Smart contracts (SC) live on the blockchain. They are not aware of the existence of any HTML element. So, you can't read the contents of any HTML element using your SC. Perhaps, you mean you are trying to read the contents of HTML elements on the frontend and pass those values to calls to the functions of the SC. In that case, you should be using regular JavaScript to read the contents of the element and interact with the SC using a library like web3.js or ether.js

Unless you mean something else, in which case you should elaborate a bit more on your question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.